# Understanding equivariance of the Tate construction $(-)^{tC_P}$

Tags: higher-category-theory, higher-algebra, equivariant-homotopy

$\DeclareMathOperator\Sp{Sp}\DeclareMathOperator\Fun{Fun}\newcommand\Cat{\text{Cat}}\DeclareMathOperator\CoInd{CoInd}\newcommand\Spaces{\text{Spaces}}$It is stated in line 10, p76, Thomas Nikolaus, Peter Scholze, *On topological cyclic homology*, arXiv:[1707.01799](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.01799).

> The functor $(-)^{tC_p}:\Sp^{BC_p}\rightarrow \Sp$ is $BC_p$ equivariant, by Theorem I.4.1.

I have two confusions here

**Q1.** How are $\Sp^{BC_p}$ and $\Sp$ regarded as $BC_p$ equivariant objects?

---

In the spirit of Maxime's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/376586) to [How does one rigorously lift a map $Sp \rightarrow Sp$ of spectra to equivariant spectra?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376575/how-does-one-rigorously-lift-a-map-sp-rightarrow-sp-of-spectra-to-equivariant) (which I clearly haven't internalized), my understanding is that we should have an adjunction
$$ \Fun(B(BC_p), \Cat) \xrightarrow{U} \Cat$$
with right adjoint $\CoInd$, such that $\CoInd(\Sp) \simeq \Sp^{BC_p}$.

---

**Q2.** How does the result followm from I.4.1?

Comment: presumably $BC_p$ acts on itself by translation and hence on the functor category $\mathsf{Fun}(\mathrm{B}C_p, \mathsf{Sp})$, and it acts trivially on $\mathsf{Sp}$. (Be careful not to confuse a BC_p action for a C_p action!) for Q2, I'd guess they're pointing to I.4.1 since it gives a statement that is manifestly functorial in the Kan complex S.

Comment: Thanks Dylan, for Q1, i edited slightly  -  is what I comment what we should expect? For Q2, Im confused with your comment, I hope you don't mind elaborating.

Comment: for your edit: a BC_p-equivariant object in Cat would be a functor from B(BC_p) to Cat, not from BC_p to Cat.

Comment: for Q2: Let S be a Kan complex. Then the diagonal p^*: Sp-->Sp^S is certainly Aut(S)-equivariant for the trivial action on the source. It follows that the right adjoint p_* inherits an Aut(S)-action. Now, there is a localization functor Fun(Sp^S, Sp)-->Fun(Sp^S,S) (modulo set theory) which approximates a functor by one which annihilates the 'induced' objects; so this functor then induces a functor on Aut(S)-equivariant objects. The value of the functor on p_* is p_*^T. Now apply the discussion to the case S=BC_p and restrict the Aut(BC_p) action to BC_p, which acts on itself by translation

Comment: I'm still lost by "so this functor then induces a functor on Aut(S)-equivariant objects. " - but I should think about this for some more time then come back. And yes! I had a typo on Q1.

Comment: It might be helpful to work out precisely what is a $BC_p$-action on a category. It is a fun exercise, and I won't spoil the answer here :).

Comment: @BryanShih if $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ is a functor, then it induces a functor $\mathsf{Fun}(BG, \mathcal{C}) \to \mathsf{Fun}(BG, \mathcal{D})$ by composition. Now take $\mathcal{C}=\mathcal{D} = \mathsf{Fun}(\mathsf{Sp}^S, \mathsf{Sp})$, $G=\mathrm{Aut}(S)$, and $F$ the 'Verdier localization' (again, modulo set theory- really one should work with the category of $\kappa$-accessible functors for some $\kappa$).

Comment: Ah! Thanks a lot Dylan. Ok, Denis!  It seems to me that the whole paper is based a lot on enriched category theory (enriched in $Cat$) of the category $Cat^{BG}$ where $G$ is a simplicial group. For example: we have the adjunction $Fun^{BG}(C,D^{triv}) = Fun(C_{hG}, D^{triv})$ (Hopefully i got this correct). Are there any articles that systemically treats these "enriched" adjunctions?

Comment: (I think that should say `$\mathsf{Fun}^G(C, D^{triv})$'.) I don't think 'enriched' is so important here (or elsewhere in the paper). The functor $\mathsf{Fun}(-, \mathcal{D}): \mathsf{Cat}^{op} \to \mathsf{Cat}$ is a right adjoint so it sends colimits to limits; in particular colimits over $BG$-shaped diagrams get sent to limits.